# How to TCP video streaming from C++ server to Java client?

Tags: java

I wanna stream a video from C++ server (TCP/IP) and read it from Java Client, but the issue is that I have never worked with Java, but I have started writing some part of it and I really appreciate if you could show me how to finish it.

The C++ server sends the captured video as following:

```
Mat img, imgGray;
img = Mat::zeros(600 , 600, CV_8UC1);

if (!img.isContinuous()) {
    img = img.clone();
}

int imgSize = img.total() * img.elemSize();
int bytes = 0;
int key;

if ( ! img.isContinuous() ) {
      img = img.clone();
      imgGray = img.clone();
}

while(1) {

            cap >> img;

            cvtColor(img, imgGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

            if ((bytes = send(socket, imgGray.data, imgSize, 0)) < 0){
                 break;
            }
}
```

and Java Client should receive it as (the folloing is C++ but I wanna do the same in Java):

```
Mat img;
img = Mat::zeros(600 , 600, CV_8UC1);
int imgSize = img.total() * img.elemSize();
uchar *iptr = img.data;
int bytes = 0;
int key;

if ( ! img.isContinuous() ) {
      img = img.clone();
}

while (key != 'q') {

    if ((bytes = recv(socket, iptr, imgSize , MSG_WAITALL)) == -1) {
        std::cerr << "receiving failed" << std::endl;
    }

    cv::imshow(img);
```

Here is the Java code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

class TCPClient {
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {

Mat img;

Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 3000);
BufferedReader from_server = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

img = Mat.zeros(480, 640, CvType.CV_8UC1);
int imgSize = (int) (img.total() * img.elemSize());


clientSocket.close();
}
}
```